# Trigger a cloud function every time I create a new user

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux, firebase-authentication

I am using the `react-redux-firebase` framework (http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/auth.html). I have a function deployed that is triggered on the `functions.auth.user().oncreate` event. The flow is as follows:

1. User logs in
2. Document for the user is created in my `users` collection
3. function triggers and appends fields to the user document on top of the default fields that google adds

This is working.

I've then implemented CRUD functions on the `user` collection. When I delete a user document through my implemented CRUD functions in the UI, it successfully deletes from the firestore. However, when I re-log back in with the user, it will re-create the user document, but only with the default google fields, it doesn't re-trigger the function again.

It seems that Google remembers who has logged in before, and the `.onCreate` will only trigger on new logins.

To get functions to trigger again, I have to go into the Firebase dashboard and delete the user from the authentication table, then re-login.

[image: firebase dashboard]
[image: delete in menu]

How do I make sure that that `.onCreate` will trigger on the `users` collection, instead of on firebase authentications?

Comment: Do you want to learn how to trigger a function when you add user data to the database or do you want to learn how to delete a user from the authentication module? Answers to both have been provided below. Please edit the title of this question based on which answer you accept so that it's useful for other future people searching with the same  problem.

Answer (score 1):

`onCreate` in the context of an authentication trigger is behaving as it should. It only triggers when you create a new user. When you log back in with the same user you are not creating a new user, therefore the function is not triggered. You are only deleting the user in your database, not the user in firebase authentication.

If you want to trigger a function based on a user document being created in a  collection then you will need to write a database function. This will need to be a real-time DB or firestore trigger depending on where you are storing the user data.

So if you wanted the function to trigger every time a user document is created in firestore it would look like this:

```
exports.updateUser = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}')
    .onCreate((change, context) => {
      // Your logic
    });
```

Alternatively, a real-time database trigger would look similar but you replace *firestore* with *database*. So...

```
exports.updateUser = functions.database.ref('users/{userId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
      // Your logic
    });
```

You are not limited to triggering on an create, you can trigger on update, write and delete aswell.

Here are relevant docs on [Firestore Triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events)

Here are docs on [Real time DB Triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, you aren't deleting the user itself, just their user data in stored in Cloud Firestore. When you properly delete a user, it should fire any [`onDelete` authentication functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#trigger_a_function_on_user_deletion) you have set up.

To delete a user using client-side code, you need to use:

```js
firebase.auth().currentUser.delete()
  .then(function() {
    console.log('Successfully deleted user');
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error deleting user:', error);
  });
```

If you want to delete a user from Cloud Functions, you would instead use:

```js
admin.auth().deleteUser(uid) // maybe get uid from the deleted document ID?
  .then(function() {
    console.log('Successfully deleted user');
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error deleting user:', error);
  });
```